# Windows Azure Caching get instance of cache item just before it gets deleted

Tags: caching, azure

I'm using Azure Caching (Worker role with Local cache support) to cache some items. No I would like to save the cached item to Azure storage table before it gets removed from the cache by eviction. I know that I can hook into the remove notification from the server, but it just tells me the key that has been removed without any reference to the actual object. Does someone know how to workaround this issue?

I have been thinking about generating some sort of threads that would check if the items are still available and I would delete the timer and create new one every time object in cache gets fiddled with. Problem with this solution is that I soon have 100000 timers running wild on my server. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the windows azure cache is not reliable, we had sort of the same issue, so if you want reliability, cache won't provide you with 100%. Secondly, try to increase "Time To Live" in your cloud instance file, and expiration time I would guess "Absolute". You can do that by going to the properties of the cloud instance and then select Caching.

Comment: "Azure cache is not reliable" - in what way? Did you enable High Availability for your cache and allocate multiple instances?

Comment: Well, we had consultants directly from Microsoft (we paid for consultancy service) and themselves said that you can't rely on the cache. I did a quick google lookup to find that, couldn't though. I'm sure if you drill deep you will definitely find references.

Comment: Additionally if AH is enabled, that adds a delay to allow for data replication. So in effect you might be asking for data in Node2 and still hasn't been replicated from Node1. You will need to implement a retry policy to tackle that.

Comment: Plus, cache in its nature is a very volatile/sensible medium.

Comment: @David Makogon: correction: Microsoft said Azure cache is not reliable in the way we want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to put the item into storage just before it expires, put it there on create. As others have said caches of all types should be considered volatile.

This may not be the answer you're looking for if you're using cache to make it fast to save updates to an item.